# MySQL - Select where title like in %x% - Wildcard like in

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

I have table with titles (title column)

And table with censored words (name column).

Example title can be like: `Ever Sex Mount!`

And one of the censored words in another table is `sex`

And `sex` appears in the title `Ever Sex Mount!`

So this record should be excluded from the result set.

So...

How can I SELECT all records from one table, where their titles don't use any banned words from another table that aggregates them using `name` column

It's about substring. Normally done by like... `WHERE title NOT LIKE "%sex%"` I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would seem to want:

```
select t.*
from titles t
where not exists (select 1
                  from bannedwords bw
                  where t.title not like '%' + bw.name + '%'
                 );
```

Of course, course, this logic will also exclude any titles with "Essex" or "Sussex" or "Middlesex" or "sextuplet" and so on.